# Give a context-free grammar that generates the language

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar, finite-automata

**Give a context-free grammar that generates the language:**

$\{a^i b^j c^k d^h \mid i, j, h \geq 0, k>0 \text{ and } i+j \leq h\}$

This is what I've done so far:

$S \rightarrow aSb \mid bSc \mid cSd \mid D$

$D \rightarrow dD \mid d$

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a tutorial on how to format your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your construction fails to make sure that the $a$'s stay in front of the $b$'s, note that it allows $S \to bSc \to baSbc \to baDbc \to badbc$.  This example also shows that you need to make sure there are at least as many $d$'s as $a$'s and $b$'s combined.

The following rules should work:
$$
S \to aSd \mid T \\
T \to bTd \mid U \\
U \to Ud \mid cU \mid c
$$
Note how the rules $S \to aSd, T\to bTd$ ensure that $i+j \le h$, and the addition of the intermediate nonterminal $T$ makes sure the $a$'s are all in front of the $b$'s.